# Deserialize JSON of unknown type in ASP.NET Core C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am writing an ASP.NET Core service that's a basic passthrough for now. It should receive JSON from another server and send it to the client as is.

Let's say the other server serves this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Sleep","isComplete":false}]
```

my passthrough calls **HttpClient.GetStringAsync** the problem is that it returns a string not an object :

```
 "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Sleep\",\"isComplete\":false}]"
```

That's not what I need. So how do I get the original? I do not see a GetXXX method in HttpClient that will return arbitrary object (that would be plan A).
I tried **HttpClient.GetAsync** but that does not return the JSON either it returns HttpResponseMessage that contains everything (headers status etc.) EXCEPT the desired JSON 
Plan B is to convert the string into an object but even if I ignore extra cycles spent on it, I don't know the object type in advance. I tried Newtonsoft's

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>
```

and also

```
JObject.Parse
```

neither worked. I also tried RegEx.Unescape - no dice.
Is HttpClient may be not the right tool for this? Or am I using it wrong?

Comment: if you have to return json.. why not return the json as it is?

Comment: Great how do I get JSON as it is? Did you read the question?

Comment: `GetStringAsync` will return the JSON string. the string you shared shows extra \ to escape `"`. But when you display the JSON in the UI or return from the method or return to the client as string it will be the original content only. This is not the special case happening to you. Any string which has `"` in it will show `\\` in front of it when you see them in debugger.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fjMh7X

Comment: GetStringAsync returns a string not an object. If I return that string as my response it will return what I posted (I got it from the browser). Your example is a console application that is not how it works in ASP.NET response

Comment: What different will it make if you return the object... it will be converted to JSON only and return to the browser.. I think you need to add more details and relevant code in the question. It will help us understand the issue better and provide more appropriate solution.

Comment: JSON is text. Not a different type or object, just a string with a specific format. If you want to return a JSON string you retrieved from a file, database or remote site to your own caller, just return that string with the correct content-type. `var thatString=await client.GetStringAsync(url); return Content(thatString, "application/json");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use net 6+ minimal api

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

 var jsonString = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Sleep\",\"isComplete\":false}]";
  
  return Results.Content(jsonString, "application/json");
```

else

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

  return Content(jsonString, "application/json");
```

Comment: I do not get Content as available object in the C# code of my ASP.NET Core 6.0 application. Where is it defined?